# Objective-C - "Expected expression" error

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm still in my first forays into Objective-C. Can anybody tell me why this this code showing a compiler error `expected expression`?

```
float total = (self.slider1.value * 255) + (self.slider2.value * 255) + (self.slider3.value * 255);

if (float > 700.0f){
    UIColor* color = [[UIColor alloc] initWithWhite:1 alpha:1];
} else {
    UIColor* color = [[UIColor alloc] initWithWhite:0 alpha:1];
}
```

The error is for the `if` line.

Comment: `if (total > 700.0f)` instead of `if (float > 700.0f)` ? Can't use the keyword `float` as the name of a variable

Comment: I think this is the funniest mistake I ever seen on SO :))) Probably to much work for today Matt, you should take a break.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You probably want:

```
if (total > 700.0f) {
```

The word `float` is the *type* of the variable, not the name of it.

Comment: Dang, I'm so stupid. Can't believe I was staring at that for 30 minutes. Thanks

Comment: There are no smart mistakes!

Answer (score 0):

Issue is with:

```
if (float > 700.0f)
```

**`float` is a keyword.**

change it to:

```
if (total> 700.0f)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have missed.

```
float total = (self.slider1.value * 255) + (self.slider2.value * 255) + (self.slider3.value * 255);

if (`float` > 700.0f){
    UIColor* color = [[UIColor alloc] initWithWhite:1 alpha:1];
} else {
    UIColor* color = [[UIColor alloc] initWithWhite:0 alpha:1];
}
```

Change `float` to total.